# Comparing multiple values to multiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a couple of select boxes and I need the rows that I have to be compared to those select boxes.

So lets say I have 3 select boxes

```
#brand_id, #model_id, #memory_id
```

And the value is empty on default. So I need to check if it is selected and if it is selected I want to add it to an array. If a box is not selected it should add all the ids of that box.

The condition I can think of would be this:

```
//Phones array contains all the rows
    var filterArray = [];
    if($("#brand").val() != ''){
        $.each(phones, function(index, value){
            if(value.brand_id == $("#brand").val()){
                filterArray.push(value.id);
            }
        });
    }
    if($("#brand").val() != '' && $("#model").val() != ''){
        $.each(phones, function(index, value){
            if(value.model_id == $("#brand").val() && value.model_id == $("#model").val()){
                filterArray.push(value.id);
            }
        });
    }
```

And so on I hope I made clear what I mean there would be a lot more conditions to cover all options up. And with each select box that I would add the options would greatly increase with this method so I would have to add even more conditions.

Actually it is just like when you validate on errors in a form, and you want a specific error for all possible conditions even when there are multiple errors you get a list of all the errors. Only here it adds the id to an array instead of showing an error.

Comment: whats the questions? do you need better way to do this?

Comment: Yes what would be the best and shortest way to do this?

Comment: can you post html.. might help us in understanding the problem better

Comment: Well the html is just 4 select boxes. But the scenario is a vacancy website with filters where you can select the where you can select different options. But if you don't select one of the select boxes it should not search for an empty value for that value. Sorry I find it hard to explain. But it's exactly like the 3 selectboxes here: http://www.akzonobel.com/careers/vacancy_bank/